# JodaTime: How do I get the human-readable name of a DateTimeZone

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

The method `org.joda.time.getName(long instant)` requires a `long`, I don't understand what this **"instant"** is and the documentation doesn't address the question.

I have a `DateTimeZone` that I generated from a timezone ID, and all I want now is the readable name. Why do I have to pass it a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `instant` is the time in milliseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z to get the name for.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#getName%28long%29

Comment: Right, I saw that. But I'm trying to say that I don't understand the purpose of this, or what value I should enter exactly. I just want the textual name of the timezone, why do I need to enter a 1970, 2011, or 2050 for that matter?? Isn't the name of the time zone still going to be the name of the time zone? Should I just use the current System.currentTimeMillis()?

Comment: The function gets you the timezone. For example `+01:00` for Germany. In the summer you get `+02:00` because of the daylight saving time.

Comment: I have to agree with the David Parks here. That API makes *no sense*.

Comment: So passing in System.currentTimeMillis() is correct then because some names will be different at different times of the year. I guess I get the reason, if only they just said that in the docs. :)  Thanks!